# How can I reset auto-run settings for removable devices?

Tags: android

I have an android phone I'm working on, and I accidentally clicked "do nothing" when the little window asking me what to do when it plugged in popped up. Now, `adb devices` shows that the device isn't even recognized. How can I change the default behavior?

I went to Applications -> System Tools -> System Preferences -> Removable Media and set everything to "Ask me what to do," but it seems that the settings are stored specifically for this device. Any tips on finding where the settings are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `adb devices` doesn't show it, then your udev configuration needs to be corrected, and udev restarted. Perhaps then it will show up in the Removable Media area.